# Adobe Premiere Pro doesn't recognize the GPU

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, cuda, adobe-premiere

I'm using as a GPU the Nvidia GeForce GTX 1070, and I installed the NVIDIA CUDA software from the official NVIDIA website. When I open a project I always select (CUDA) for the rendering environment, but when I'm starting the rendering, my GPU doesn't start, the GPU usage and the temperatures remain the same, and Adobe Premiere Pro starts using the CPU.

How can I solve it? Is there a way to to control if Premiere Pro uses the GPU?

Comment: I found step-by-step instructions for unlocking the Nvidia GeForce GTX 1070 graphics card in Adobe Premiere at [How to unlock your NVIDIA card for Premiere CC 2014, CC, CS6, CS5.5 and CS5 For Windows Users](https://www.studio1productions.com/Articles/PremiereCS5-2.htm). Does your Adobe Premier Pro software match this description? If it isn't supported, please comment about your Adobe Premier Pro version.

Comment: @karel it is the cc version! After, can you answer me on the answer box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a program called Cuda.zip that will unlock the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 graphics card in Adobe Premiere automatically. Cuda.zip can be downloaded from [How to unlock your NVIDIA card for Premiere CC 2014, CC, CS6, CS5.5 and CS5 For Windows Users](https://www.studio1productions.com/Articles/PremiereCS5-2.htm).

The Cuda.zip archive contains the following three files.

- cuda.bat
- Cuda Install Instructions.txt
- cuda_supported_cards.txt

The following instructions were copied from Cuda Install Instructions.txt

#### Program instructions

> 1. Follow these steps exactly. Remember Adobe Premiere must be installed on the C: drive.
> 2. Download the Cuda.zip file and save it to the C: drive on your computer.
> 3. When you download the program, please pay attention to where you are saving it to.  You MUST save the program to your C: hard drive.
> 4. Find the program on your hard drive and unzip it. Windows users, just right-click on the Cuda.zip file and select "Extract All"  to
>    unzip it OR use whatever other program you have for unzipping files.
>
>    Make Sure You exit From Adobe Premiere BEFORE Running the Program, or else it will not work.
> 5. There is a Cuda Install Instruction file with the cuda.bat file.  MAKE SURE YOUR READ IT. Right-click on the cuda.bat file and select
>    Run as Administrator. (This is the most important step.)
> 6. The program program brings up a menu giving you options for different programs.
>
>    Make your selection. Then you will get a message that says "The CUDA Supported Card file has been updated."  That's it. Simple wasn't
>    it? But, you're not done yet.
> 7. Now startup After Premiere and open or create a project.
> 8. Then at the top of the screen select *Project*, then select *Project Settings* and select *General*.
> 9. Look under *Rendering and Playback* in the window, it will say: `Renderer:  Mercury Playback Engine GPU Hardware` If it says --
>    `Renderer: Mercury Playback Engine Software Only` simply change it for
>    `Mercury Playback Engine GPU Hardware` and you are done.